# Is it possible to select either image or video from camera intent simultaneously from test application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to Android OS. I am trying to understand how does camera intent work by writing small test application. For this purpose, I have looked at the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html to understand the basics.

question: 
Is it possible to launch camera with intent (or some other way) such that both actions of selecting either image or video are available simultaneously.

I have had done bit of research of looking at similar type of question related to gallery, and one of the suggestion was related to setting a mime type on intent with setType("*/*"), but this leads user to the list of types to select from, rather than selecting from image or video.

While selecting image from camera using image capture action as below,
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); I could see that when camera is launched the toggle button ( between camcorder and camera ) is not available for selection.
and vice versa.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is not possible to combine image and video mime types, while firing intent, as they work atomically.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA` This intent does not support activity results or specific intent file outputs. This intent is designed to simply open the camera. The functionality you seek does not exist natively in Android.